# Get-PnPListitem with query filtered by number, converted to string, not working

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a powershell script where I need to get some items from SharePoint online list, filtered by one value in string column, and it only works if I put value in quotes.

```
$Number=123 # NOT working, no values returned from SP
[string]$Number=123 # NOT working, no values returned from SP
$Number="123" # WORKING
```

and then

```
$query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Number'/><Value Type='Text'>$Number</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";   
$NumberInfo = (Get-PnPListitem -List SPList -Query $query).FieldValues
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any issues. Have two columns: One as **Single Line of Text** and the other **Number**. Both cases, without quote worked for me. See the test script below.

```
$Number=45 #worked

$query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='NumberAsText'/><Value Type='Text'>$Number</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";   
$NumberInfo = (Get-PnPListitem -List ProjectList -Query $query).FieldValues
$NumberInfo.NumberAsText

$Number=23 #Worked here as well

$query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='NumberAsNumber'/><Value Type='Number'>$Number</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";   
$NumberInfo = (Get-PnPListitem -List ProjectList -Query $query).FieldValues
$NumberInfo.NumberAsNumber
```